# PowerShell 2.0 - How to request data from password protected website?

Tags: html, powershell, request, powershell-2.0

I tried to request information from the website on my facebook page.

view-source:https://www.facebook.com/myFacebookName

And this is what I tried, because I need a login and password to get the information above from facebook. So I tried this code:

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$credCache = new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
$creds = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("myEmailAddress","myPassword")
$credCache.Add("http://www.facebook.com/", "Basic", $creds)
$webclient.Credentials = $credCache
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString("http://www.facebook.com/")

$fbtextfile = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('view-source:https://www.facebook.com/myFacebookName')
$fbtextfile | out-file C:\Test1\process.txt
```

But unfortunatley it doesn't work :(
Anyway, is it possible to get these information from my password protected account on facebook.com ?
By the way, what I have to put in 'Basic' in the 4th code line.

Comment: I don't think FB's authentication system would allow you to do this. However, there is an dedicated API to get data from FB.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Facebook's authentication system would allow you to do this.

They have a specific API dedicated to getting information from them.

You can start here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5